# Capturing Screen from iPhone using QuickTime disables sounds on device

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, quicktime, screen-capture

I'm not able to play any sound on iPhone device after connecting it via lighting cable to Macbook Pro and enabling "Movie Recording" from this iPhone in QuickTime Player.

My goal is not to record movie just displaying on the screen what is going on iPhone but I with sound on device. After enabling screen capture session from iPhone to MacBook screen I can't hear any sound from my iPhone.

I can hear only audio when:
- I connect headset to iPhone then I can hear the sound in headphones.
- The sound is getting back after disabling capture screen session in QuickTime but this is not what I want because now I don't see iPhone screen on MacBook screen.

Am I doing something wrong?

My MacBook OSX: 10.11.6, iOS: 10.0.2

Answer (score 1):

In order to record the sound from the mobile too, you have to enable the microphone[image]

Make sure your phone is checked for both Camera and Microphone. If it crashes/ closes, do not worry. Launch the movie recording again. It should start recording both screen and sounds from your iPhone/ iPad.

Comment: Dear @ArunB, the question is not about recording, but about outputting sound from the device itself.

Comment: @Cœur Until, you tap on that red button, it doesn't record. It will output the sound from the device. Click on that arrow next to record button and select your device. It will start outputting sound and screen

Answer (score -1):

You tried, true, but change cable then it works fine.
I think your cable is interrupted connection.

Comment: Tried 3 different cables from three different iOS developers.